# Correlation coefficients when oversampling the extremes of a normal distribution

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, effect-size, pearson-r, psychology

Running some simulations in which I generated two correlated normal variables (rho=0.3), and then took samples of this population in which the extremes of the population where oversampled (specifically by splitting the X variable into 5 equal-interval groups and sampling an equal N from each group). The average correlation for the simulated samples was ~0.5. I was wondering whether this might be a valid procedure for finding effects that are more pronounced at the extremes (e.g., in the context of psychiatric symptoms where the extremes are most important).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I wonder if you're using this as a proxy for something called *cokurtosis*.

Comment: 1. You said you generated random variable and took samples from *population*. I think, unless very huge sample was simulated, your population is actually sample and the sample correlation may not be 0.3. If it is higher then that can also influence your later samples' correlation.

Comment: 2. If I understand correctly you are simulating a two-dimensional vector X? How are you constructing intervals for $\mathbb{R}^2$? I